# ServiceManager cannot get globally configured logger when access through phpunit

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a model that implements:

```
\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
```

The model relies on a logger that is defined in \configs\autoload\global.php and retrieved by doing:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get("Zend\Log")
```

This works great if I'm on a webpage, but in phpunit, the same code breaks with the message:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Log"
```

Why would the service manager be able to get the logger when running this from the web, but not from phpunit?

Testconfig.php.dist contains:

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in TestConfig.php.dist was wrong. It should have been

```
../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
```